# Opening .gz file for MNIST dataset

Tags: python, numpy, mnist

We need to open the original MNIST dataset consisting of greyscale values of handwritten numbers [0-9].

The code looks like this:

```
def load_data(path):
    with np.load(path) as f:
        x_train, y_train = f['x_train'], f['y_train']
        x_test, y_test = f['x_test'], f['y_test']
        return (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = load_data('../input/????')




The original MNIST dataset however, consists of 4 files, 

train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz:  training set images (9912422 bytes) 
train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz:  training set labels (28881 bytes) 
t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz:   test set images (1648877 bytes) 
t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz:   test set labels (4542 bytes)
```

How can I open this in the best way?

Comment: `import gzip` `f=gzip.open('train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz','rb')` `file_content=f.read()`

Comment: Any reason why you can't `from sklearn.datasets import load_digits; digits = load_digits()`?

Comment: because it's not all digits, the console says

Answer (score 0):

```
import gzip

with gzip.open('/content/data/MNIST/raw/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz','r') as f:
   image_size = 28
   num_images = 10000
   f.read(16)
   buffer = f.read(image_size * image_size * num_images)
   data = np.frombuffer(buffer, dtype=np.uint8).astype(np.float32)
   data = data.reshape(num_images, image_size, image_size, 1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).